# Weird axis arrows appeared

Tags: axis

These things started appearing from nowhere when i click an object.

[image]
[image]

When i try to move the object, the axes move, the object doesnt.

[image: Using move tool moves only the axes, but the object stands still]

I assume i just touched some setting by mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you have set it so transformations only affect the origin of the object, to disable this setting,
go to Options then disable Origins

[image]

There is also a very similar looking thing that one can accidentally enable under Gizmos > Object Gizmos

[image]

Comment: Hey :). Also, Transform origins is under *Sidebar > Tool > Transform* (if you don't have toolbar enabled). I don't think *Object Gizmos* are related here, which 'thing' do you have in mind?